# Syntax error 256 in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a field in my table and I keep getting this syntax error.

```
global $conn, $strTableName;
db_exec("UPDATE equipment SET EContractNum = " . $_SESSION[$strTableName."_masterkey1"] . " WHERE EContractNum = " . $values['EContractNum'], $conn);
```

Here is the error:

> Error type: 256 Error Description: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE econtractnum=35867111' at line
>   1

I have looked at several searchs that are similair to mine but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am fairly new at this so it is probably something simple. I just cant seem to make it work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please brush up on your [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you do yourself some serious harm.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION[$strTableName."_masterkey1"]` is probably empty, or a string that needs to be quoted.

Also, don't put the raw values of variables into queries like that. Use a framework or prepared statements. It's good for security and it would also prevent this kind of error (well, it'd turn it into a different kind of error, at least).